# PyQt5 : close QfileDialog after clicking Open and returning file

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, pyside

I'm pretty new to PyQt5...
With that said, I've added a menu with File->Open.
I've implemented this using QFileDialog.

```
        # Create the Actions for the Menu Bar
        LoadVrfAction = QAction("&Load New File", self)
        LoadVrfAction.setShortcut("Ctrl-N")
        LoadVrfAction.setStatusTip("New VRF Data")
        LoadVrfAction.triggered.connect(self.control.loadVrfFile)

        menuBar  = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&File")
        fileMenu.addAction(LoadVrfAction)
```

```
  def loadVrfFile(self):
    vrfFileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.view, "Open File")
    myFile = vrfFileName[0]

    # Load the file
    logging.debug(f"Start: Reading File = {myFile}")
    self.view.core.readVrfFile(myFile)
    logging.debug(f"End: Reading File = {myFile}")
```

My problem is that when I click "Open" on the file I want to load, I want the Menu Dialog box to go hide or go away before I execute the function "readVrfFile".  Since the file I'm reading into the program is large it takes about 15 seconds and my diaglog box just appears frozen while it's loading.

Is there an easy way to hide the getOpenFileName box and instead print status to a textbox/status bar while its loading?

Comment: The problem is not in the dialog, but in what you do within `readVrfFile()`, which is probably something very demanding for the CPU and completely blocks the event loop until it's finished. So, we need to know what you actually do in that function.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  Yes, that function is using pandas to read a very large CSV file and create many classes that will be used in the program.  It is very memory/cpu intensive and takes about 8-9 seconds to process.  Is there something I can do to let the event loop do it's thing before I jump into an intensive function?

Comment: @musicamante your hint helped me, and you were indeed correct thanks!  I added QApplication.processEvents() to clear out any pending events before jumping into the "expensive" function call.  This closed the window and went to the next step.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If the computing takes that much time, you shall consider using a QThread subclass with proper signals (remember, ***no*** access to UI elements is allowed from external threads, including *creation). `processEvents()` is a basic workaround, but it should never be considered as the final solution.

Comment: @musicamante yep thanks.  I spent the extra time to learn QThread/QThreadPool last night and its a way more elegant solution.  My first solution was indeed just a workaround.  I think I'm well armed to handle GUI freezes at this point in a correct by construction method.  Thanks again for the pointers in the right direction.